# Putting objects into a bucket in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket_name = sys.argv[1]
object_name = sys.argv[2]
try:
 response = s3.Object(bucket_name,
object_name).put(Body=open(object_name, 'rb'))
 print (response)
except Exception as error:
 print (error)
```

That's my put_bucket function that puts objects into buckets but I need it done with little to no user input once I call the main program, basically automatic.

```
import sys
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-1')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
keyname = 'AlexBpem.pem'
user_data = '''#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd'''
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='ec2-assignbuke2',CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'})
sg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='MyWebServer', Description = 'WebServer', VpcId='vpc-0dea879f34afff60d')

instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-0fc970315c2d38f01',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano',
 KeyName = 'AlexBpem',
 UserData = user_data, 
 SecurityGroupIds=[ sg.group_id ],
 SubnetId = 'subnet-06add059500af7905' 
)

for bucket_name in sys.argv[1:]:
 try:
     response = s3.create_bucket(Bucket=ec2-assignbuke2,
CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'})
     print (response)
 except Exception as error:
     print (error)
```

Is my main program, how would I go abouts using (def) functions within my code to make this call automatic.

Comment: What does launching an EC2 instance have to do with this? What do you mean when you say you want to automate uploading objects to S3? How would the uploading script know what S3 key to apply to the uploaded file?

Comment: It's just my overall project, it's a step within many but this one I am having issues with, basically there needs to be little to no user input. It would work when I input the command python3 put_bucket.py (bucket name) (object name) but rather than that I need it to be executable by the command ./put_bucket.py (bucket name) (object name) which it is not doing currently.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the 1st code snippet into a function and how to import that into the 2nd code snippet (as an imported function that the 2nd snippet can call)?

Comment: I need to use functions (def) within my 2nd snippet of code or import modules at the beginning and to have little to no user config I need to input parameters into the put_bucket function (1st snippet) so pretty much

Comment: So, what's stopping you turning the first code into a [function](https://realpython.com/lessons/example-function/) that takes source filename, bucket name, and bucket key as parameters, and then simply [importing](https://realpython.com/courses/python-imports-101/) that as needed?

Comment: The process of it, I'm not sure where I would input the parameters from the first code into the second and also where are you getting the bucket key from?

Comment: Like would I create the function in my 2nd piece of code with the parameters you mentioned (still not sure where bucket key comes from) or no? I'm not too good at programming which is why I am here trying to improve by learning from solutions and seeing how people did what and how to implement into my own.

Comment: Unless your script is hard-coded to always upload the same file, then whoever/whatever runs your script is going to have to supply the name of the file to be uploaded. You typically do that through command line parameters, as in your first code snippet. How you determine the S3 object key is largely up to you - you could make it the same as the filename part of the file being uploaded but be aware that that could potentially cause problems (if two different files with the same name were uploaded, or if a filename included a character that's not supported by S3).

Comment: Yeah it will only be me accessing it so I can just keep deleteing / renaming files that have the same name, I just need help knowing how to actually start coding this into my program because everything else I did fine, this part just has me stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert your inline 'upload to S3' code into a function, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

def upload_to_s3(filename, bucket, key):
  try:
    response = s3.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=open(filename, 'rb'))
    print (response)
    return response
  except Exception as error:
    print (error)
```

To call this function, you can do this:

```
file = '/home/users/james/dogs/toto.png'
bkt = 'mybucket'
key = 'dogs/tot.png'
rsp = upload_to_s3(file, bkt, key)
```